# Angle between two specific vectors, having trouble finding the right vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

The question says that the height of a hill is $z=10-2x^2-y^2$, and that an ant is moving on the hill in such a way that the coordinates of the ant on the $xy$-plane is $x(t)=t$, $y(t)=\sqrt{t}$. At the point $(1,1)$ on the $xy$-plane, what is the angle between the direction in which the ant is moving and the direction in which the height of the hill increases most rapidly?

I know I am supposed to find the tangent vector for both the height of the hill and the movement of the ant, then take the dot product to find the angle, but I am having trouble finding the directional vector for the ant. Any ideas?

Comment: Just find its velocity vector at point $(1,1)$ by $r'(t)=(x'(t),y'(t)) = (1,\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}})$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The direction in which the height of the hill increases most rapidly is the **gradient** of the function at the point **(1,1)** i.e. the vector $(f_x(1,1),f_y(1,1))$.